# How do you get Craft to generate multi-paragraph text?

Tags: templating, richtext, craft-features, craft4, text

In every other CMS I've used there's an option to compose multi-paragraph text in the back end which is then parsed out into P tags in templates. Neither the native text field nor the popular Redactor field seems to do that out of the box, and I can't seem to find documentation that helps.

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple!

Comment: The plain text field won't do that but Redactor will do that by default. What are you experiencing with Redactor?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I had left P tags around the content in the template, which prevented Redactor from parsing the text the way I wanted.</s>

This wasn't it either — the field needed to be cleared out and saved and then the content re-input and re-saved after changing the field settings.